# mysql right join where returns empty on one clause

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_users as U 
RIGHT JOIN subscribers AS S ON S.userid = U.user_id 
WHERE S.approved > 0 AND S.channel_id = 1 AND S.alert_level >= 90
```

If I take off the last AND clause (AND S.alert_level >= 90) the search works exactly as expected.  Leaving on the last AND clause and I get an empty result set.

Obviously, I checked the subscribers table to make sure the userid's that would be returned had the right alert_level and they all had 90 so this should have returned 2 users... and S.alert_level is a smallint(6).

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds strange. You say you "checked the subscribers table to make sure the userid's that would be returned had the right alert_level" but why would you need to do that? You should have been able to see the alert_level already from when you tried to "take off the last AND clause (AND S.alert_level >= 90) the search works exactly as expected." Didn't you think to check that? Can you check it now?

Comment: Bang! Yep... all it took was another pair of eyes!

Comment: I reposted as an answer in case you want to edit it and/or accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the result of this query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_users as U 
RIGHT JOIN subscribers AS S ON S.userid = U.user_id 
WHERE S.approved > 0 AND S.channel_id = 1
```

Pay attention to the value of `S.alert_level` that is returned for each row in that result set. It's probably not over 90. That explains why adding the last condition gives you no rows.